# How to get id of second dropdown of dynamically generated two dropdown based on first dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropdown

I am dynamically generating 2 dropdown control on each row  so on each row i would be having 2 dropdown control.

Now consider on 1st row i am selecting 1st dropdown then on change event of 1st dropdown i would like to fill 2nd dropdown so for that i need to find id of that 1st row 2nd dropdown control.

For each row i would like to get 2nd dropdown control id based on first dropdown control selection.

So How to do that??

[image]

```js
var cnt = 1;

var obj = {
  Cars: [{
    "CarType": "BMW",
    "carID": "bmw123"
  }, {
    "CarType": "mercedes",
    "carID": "merc123"
  }, {
    "CarType": "volvo",
    "carID": "vol123r"
  }, {
    "CarType": "ford",
    "carID": "ford123"
  }]
};


function AddRow() {

  var fieldWrapper1 = $("<div class='col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 form-group' cnt ='field" + cnt + "'/>");
  var fieldWrapper2 = $("<div  class='col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 form-group' cnt ='field" + cnt + "'/>");

  var fName1 = $("<select class='coursefieldname' cnt ='drpdownCourse" + cnt + "'  name='drpdownCourseNm" + cnt + "'  />");
  var fName2 = $("<select class='fieldname' cnt ='SubCourse" + cnt + "'  name='SubCourseNm" + cnt + "'  />");

  fieldWrapper1.append(fName1);
  fieldWrapper2.append(fName2);
  var newRow = $("<div class='row' cnt ='row" + cnt + "'/>");
  $(newRow).append(fieldWrapper1);
  $(newRow).append(fieldWrapper2);
  $(newRow).insertBefore($(".add-more").parent());
  $(newRow).append("<br>");
  var courseDropdown = $('#drpdownCourse' + cnt);
  courseDropdown.empty();


  for (var i = 0; i < obj.Cars.length; i++) {
    var option = $('<option></option>').text(obj.Cars[i]['CarType']);
    $('#drpdownCourse' + cnt).empty().append(option);
  }
  cnt = cnt + 1;
}



$(document).on('change', "select.coursefieldname", function() {
  var yourSecondSelectInTheRow = $(this).closest("#field1");
  console.log(yourSecondSelectInTheRow)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><span class="add-more">&nbsp;<a onclick="AddRow()" href="#">+ Add</a></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Try `$(document).on('change', 'select', function() {
    var nextSelect = $(this).parent().next().children('select');
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `select` elements are dynamically generated, you'll need to use event delegation to bind event on it.

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function () {
    var nextSelectName = $(this).parent().next().children('select').attr('name');
});
```

1. `$(this)` is the element that is changed. `select` element
2. `.parent()` will select the direct parent of the element
3. `next()` will select the direct next sibling element
4. `children('select')` will select the direct children `<select>` element
5. `attr('name')` gives the value of the `name` attribute

Answer (score 2):

If i understand correctly you want to get the second dropdown when the first one changes.

Using closest will get you the closest parent that has the condition id=FieldContainer and after that you can just search that div for your subcourse select.

I used $("body").on(...) so that dinamycally added elements will have the change event handled

```
 $("body").on("change", "select#drpdownCourse", function(){
     var yourSecondSelectInTheRow = $(this).closest("#FieldContainer").find("select#drpdownSubCourse");
 });
```

Comment: Sorry but in the find function you have fixed 2nd dropdown id and my 2nd dropdown id are generating like this drpdownSubCourse1,drpdownSubCourse2 etc..So your solution will not gonna work

Comment: then use find("select:nth-of-type(2)") this will get the second dropdown

Comment: also maybe think of adding drpdownSubCourse as a class the name doesn't have to be drpdownSubCourse, then you can do a find(".drpdownSubCourse"), doing parent navigation won't work if you change the html, try to use closest to get a parent where you are trying to search and then search for classes